# multidir error with mdButton

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to use `<md-button>` in angular-material, but it's not quite working. It's giving me a `[$compile:multidir]` error like the following: [Error link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=mdButton&p1=mdButton&p2=transclusion&p3=%3Ca%20class%3D%22md-raised%20md-primary%20md-button%22%20ng-transclude%3D%22%22%20ng-href%3D%22google.com%22%3E). Here's a Gist of my HTML (my JavaScript has too much logic/secrets and such to release right now): https://gist.github.com/zebMcCorkle/c7ba6175b0c3f510c001

Comment: You'd better create  a plnkr.co or jsfiddle demo for better debugging. As you only reference your local bower component files, we have no idea which version of each library you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had defined `md-button` for some reason last week in my store.js file. Why I have no idea, but it works now!